# Colour ramp in 2.8 only picks the last colour stop.

Tags: node-editor, color, eevee-render-engine

Im not sure whether somethings changed or I'm just doing something wrong (since im a newbie), but my colour ramp in blender 2.8 when using eevee engine only picks the colour at the last stop. My nodes were working just fine in blender 2.79, this has happened on 2 different instances when using the colour ramp. For example in the project im currently working on, I'm in rendered mode:

[image: Here it picks only yellow]

Now lets slide blue infront

[image: Here it picks only blue]

Is this all happening since Blender 2.8 is in BETA? Could someone chime in? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because Blender 2.80 is in beta.
However, there is nothing wrong with the color ramp node; it is actually the sky texture node returning solid white. Until sky texture is implemented, you can render out a full spherical HDRi (512x256 res 16bit .exr recommended) with 2.79 and use that in place of the sky texture.